# display a message coming from servlet on jsp page in javascript alert box

Tags: java, javascript

Can anyone tell me a way to display a message in javascript alert box,that message is comming from a servlet.Please help.

Comment: When do you want the message to appear to appear? Immediately after the page renders, or after the user has taken some action on the page?

Comment: when user submit the form(using form submission not using ajax) values goes to the servlet and after the operation it send the success or faliure message to the client

Comment: Then I'd do what Siger says below

Answer (score 0):

You need AJAX.
Javascript will send a request to the servlet, retrieve the message from the servlet response, and then display it in the alert box.

Various tutorials on the web, including [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

Answer (score 0):

You can store servlet variables in javascript variables, i.e. ([JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)) :

```
<script language="javascript">
   function displayObject(){
     var javascriptVar="${servletObject}";
     alert(javascriptVar);
   }
</script>
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="displayObject()"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

To be able to use `servletObject`, you first need to put it in the server as an attribute in your `doGet` or `doPost` function :

```
public class YourClassName extends HttpServlet {

  public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/yourPageName.jsp";

  public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {

     request.setAttribute( "ExampleValue", servletObject );

     this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
   }

}
```

Comment: how to get the value to servletObject from the servlet and how to send it to the jsp page which i want to show the alert

Comment: please tell me how to put server as an attribute in doGet or doPost function